# Check if post request logged me in

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to log in with a post request using the python requests module on a MediaWiki page:

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
s.auth = ('....', '....')
url = '.....'
values = {'wpName' : '....',
        'wpPassword' : '.....'}
req = s.post(url, values)
print(req.content)
```

I can't tell from the return value of the post request whether the login attempt was succesful. Is there something I can do to check this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Under normal circumstances i would advise you to go the mechanize way and make things way too easy for yourself but since you insist on requests, then let us use that.
YOu obviously have got the values right but i personally don't use the auth() function. So, try this instead.

```
import requests

url = 'https://example.com/wiki/index.php?title=Special:UserLogin'
values = {
    'wpName': 'myc00lusername',
    'wpPassword': 'Myl33tPassw0rd12'
}

session = requests.session()
r = session.post(url, data=values)
print r.cookies
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what I used to solve this.
After getting a successful login, I read the texts from 
    response.text
and compared it to the text I got when submitting incorrect information.
The reason I did this is that validation is done on the server side and Requests will get a 200 OK response whether it was successful or not.
So I ended up adding this line.

```
logged_in = True if("Incorrect Email or password" in session.text) else False
```

Answer (score 2):

Typically such an authentication mechanism is implemented using HTTP cookies. You might be able to check for the existence of a session cookie after you've authenticated successfully. You find the cookie in the HTTP response header or the sessions cookie attribute `s.cookies`.

Comment: It looks like the request did not work, as the cookie jar was empty..... if you know, is the Mediawiki page designed so that you cannot use the requests module to manually log in, or is perhaps a problem wiith my code instead?